# MySQL to Sqlite sync from PHP to mobile app (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, mysql, web-services, sqlite

To sync a mysql database with sqlite database using a PHP web app, I am going to

1. create a "view" mirror of SQLITE tables in MySQL
2. select changed data on mirror "view" in MySQL
3. use mysqldump to dump the sql for sqlite and save it in a file on server
4. download that file from mobile
5. import data directly to sqlite

another approach would be not using a middle "view" table and dump data using "SELECT" or mysqldump and parse it on the device or server, so it would be readable by sqlite

is there any disadvantages in creating a mirror "view" for each table that SQLITE needs on client devices? or is there another 'standard 'way to sync these 2 which i did not find on the internet?

**Edit:** after searching and coding some more finally i decided to go like this:

1. build "insert into ..." statement for sqlite from PHP on the server and save it to a zipped file
2. download the file on mobile and insert extracted sql directly to SQLITE

here is the php code for generating mysqldump like output:

```
/** key [SQLITE column name] => value [MySQL select column] */
$table_structure = array(
'id' => 'id',
'title' => 'title',
'type' => 'COALESCE(type, "")',  /** u need to wrap any column that is nullable like this **/
'flags' => 'COALESCE(type, "")', /** u need to wrap any column that is nullable like this **/
'view_field' => 'view_field',
'view_year' => 'view_year',
....
....
'updated_at' => 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at)');
$into_query = '';
$into_values = '';
$indexer = 0;
foreach ($table_structure as $sqlite => $mysql) {
$into_query .= (($indexer !== 0)? ',':'').$sqlite;
$into_values .= (($indexer !== 0)? ',",",':'').'"\'",'.$mysql.',"\'"';
$indexer++;
}
$output_filepath = "some where nice";
$query = 'SELECT CONCAT("INSERT INTO '.$table.'('.$into_query.') VALUES(",'.$into_values.',");") FROM '.$table.' ' ... "INTO OUTFILE $output_filepath CHARACTER SET utf8";
```

I hope it's a good approach and may help someone some day :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Approach 1: using sqlite db file**

whatever step you have mentioned in question is correct. this approach used when you have to send lots of data(many tables) from device to web/php vice versa.

its takes time in slower internet connection as well in 2G. in 3G its fast(its also depends on whatever code you have written at mobile/PHP to upload & download file).

make sure database file size is small if it large then make zip file which include database file.

---

> **Approach 2: make using json (SELECT *) parse in device**

this one is very long process when you have lost of table which have lots of fields. you have to get data from table one by one, send it to server/php its send back data after process. then you have to again insert data in device table.

this is also depends on INTERNET as well you code. its too slow for devices and take more time.

---

common things in both approach send/receive data only when its needed or on those which require for devices/PHP. do not send unused data to work fast.

Comment: thanx for the zip file tip